# If I'm using a for loop to generate a list of strings, how do I create a list of the variables, and not a list of the strings?

Tags: python

I have 5 lists named `l1`, `l2`, `l3`, `l4` and `l5`:

```
l1 = [1,2]
l2 = [3,4]
l3 = [5,6]
l4 = [7,8]
l5 = [9,10]
```

If I wanted to create a new object `A` as a list of lists, I could easily do this:

```
A = []
A.append(l1)
A.append(l2)
A.append(l3)
```

and so forth.... and `A` will look like this:

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
```

But can I use a for loop to make this easier?

Can I try:

```
A = []
    For q in range(1,6):
    temp = 'l' + str(q)
```

What do I do next?
temp is a string that essentially concatenates 'l' with number from the for loop.

So it looks like `'l1'`, `'l2'`, `'l3'`

But if I use

```
A.append(temp)
```

inside the loop, the output list will look like a list of strings `['l1', 'l2', 'l3', ....]`

I guess I'm confused because I don't know how to take a string, and then say, I don't want the string `'l1'`, I want to return the list that is variable `l1`.  I guess I'm trying to figure out if somehow, I had in my global name space variables named `l1`, `l2`, `l3` all the way to `l10000`,  how could I write code to make a new list that is a list of all the lists `l1`, `l2`, `l3` and so forth.

Comment: I suggest just using `A = [l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6]`. Can't get much more concise than that.

Comment: There are no pointers in Python.  I'm unsure of your intention; could you clarify it a bit?

Comment: Admirably, so far everyone who gave in to the temptation to mention a way you *could* do this also said that you shouldn't.  Please listen to the anti-recommendation and use a different data structure instead.  If the number after the "l" is meaningful, then it's worth being connected to the data in a more direct way (and if it's not, then it doesn't matter anyhow.)

Comment: "I have 5 lists named l1, l2, l3, l4 and l5" - **why**?

Answer (score 5):

For 5 lists just create a list:

```
A = [l1, l2, l3, l4, l5]
```

You could do it with a loop, but that will be messy. Something like:

```
A = [ vars()['l'+str(id)] for id in range(1,6) ]
```

Better would be to store your lists in something like a list or dictionary to begin with. That keeps them out of the way of other variables so you can easily refer to them as a group.

Comment: Thank you Duncan.  This was very helpful.  I will read up on the vars() documentation, but I think I can see that it will work using this.  Obviously for small lists, I wouldn't use a for loop to generate this list of lists, but if I have l1 to l10000, then I wouldn't want to do that!!!

Comment: @RobertTsai, I can't comprehend how you would generate 10000 separate variables without putting them in a list to begin with.

Comment: Please don't use vars() like this.  Take Duncan's last advice: use a single list to begin with.

Comment: @Rob: If you have lists from l1 to l10000 I guess there's some kind of automaic procedure that produce such lists so you should also be able to list them all directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more lists, try to add them to a "list list" on creation.

Otherwise, as stated in other answers, create the list:

```
A = [l1,l2,l3,l4,l5]
```

Comment: He asked for a list of lists, not one long list.

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like is that you want to dynamically reference a few instances of list objects during runtime by using a string that has a value matching one of your variable names. This is generally quite a bad idea, and I can't fathom why you would need to do this.

The problem is that you are trying to iterate over a list that doesn't actually exist. To put this in perspective, imagine if you were told to drive to a series of locations without being given directions to those locations (only the name of the building. Pentagon, Sears Tower, etc) and without even any roads between them. Roads don't build themselves, and neither do data structures.

Answer (score -3):

Another hacky way, not recommended of course:

```
l0 = [1,]
l1 = [2,]
l2 = [3,]

why_do_this = "["
for i in xrange(3):
    why_do_this += 'l%s,'%i
why_do_this+=']'
result=eval(why_do_this)
print result

[[1], [2], [3]]
```

Comment: -1: Don't give bad advice, even if you label it as bad advice.